# Slow wifi which is fixed by restarting wifi

Tags: networking, wireless

I have noticed since some time that my internet speed slows down. I will still have high connectivity, but no data goes through.
Restarting the computer or turning wifi manually off and then on again fixes the issue -- temporarily. After some times (can't say what triggers it) it worsens again. Other devices with the same network do not have the same issue.

I have looked into pico /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf, and it says

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

Following is the end of `journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`, the reports from today -- currently the internet is very slow.

```
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1544] dhcp4 (wlo1): option dhcp_lease_time      => '600'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1544] dhcp4 (wlo1): option domain_name_servers  => '193.243.129.53 76.233.127.10'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1544] dhcp4 (wlo1): option expiry               => '1686909281'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1544] dhcp4 (wlo1): option ip_address           => '192.168.51.136'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_domain_name => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_domain_search => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_host_name  => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1545] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_root_path  => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1546] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_routers    => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1546] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_static_routes => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1546] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1546] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_time_offset => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1546] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_wpad       => '1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1546] dhcp4 (wlo1): option routers              => '192.168.48.1'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1546] dhcp4 (wlo1): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.240.0'
Jun 16 11:44:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908681.1546] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed extended -> extended
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1562] dhcp4 (wlo1): option dhcp_lease_time      => '600'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1563] dhcp4 (wlo1): option domain_name_servers  => '193.243.129.53 76.233.127.10'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1563] dhcp4 (wlo1): option expiry               => '1686909581'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1563] dhcp4 (wlo1): option ip_address           => '192.168.51.136'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1564] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1564] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_domain_name => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1564] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1564] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_domain_search => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1565] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_host_name  => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1565] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1565] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1565] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1566] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1566] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1566] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1566] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_root_path  => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1566] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_routers    => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1567] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_static_routes => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1567] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1567] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_time_offset => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1568] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_wpad       => '1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1568] dhcp4 (wlo1): option routers              => '192.168.48.1'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1568] dhcp4 (wlo1): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.240.0'
Jun 16 11:49:41 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686908981.1568] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed extended -> extended
Jun 16 11:51:50 x NetworkManager[1359]: <info>  [1686909110.3100] agent-manager: agent[2aea3b4d663942e2,:1.119/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
```

`ip link` uncovered three devices:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:d8:61:ee:8c:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s31f6
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:87:9c:8f:6d:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
```

### Networking Hardware

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for x: 
  *-network:0               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 5c:87:9c:8f:6d:44
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-73-generic firmware=46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.51.136 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:b4334000-b4337fff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno2
       version: 10
       serial: 00:d8:61:ee:8c:89
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-73-generic firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:126 memory:b4300000-b431ffff
```

and

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno2      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"DN-Guest"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.32 GHz  Access Point: 3C:41:0E:5D:46:ED   
          Bit Rate=173.3 Mb/s   Tx-Power=9 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:23  Invalid misc:7   Missed beacon:0
```

### Network messages

A first `dmesg` revealed two messages: an absolute mass of skype-related messages, and the `wlo1` messages. Today, the issue happened again (and it was fine yesterday), so I am showing the messages for today

```
sudo dmesg -T | grep -i wlo1:
[Wed Jun 28 11:58:28 2023] wlo1: authenticated
[Wed Jun 28 11:58:28 2023] wlo1: associate with 3c:41:0e:5d:46:ed (try 1/3)
[Wed Jun 28 11:58:29 2023] wlo1: RX ReassocResp from 3c:41:0e:5d:46:ed (capab=0x1111 status=0 aid=7)
[Wed Jun 28 11:58:29 2023] wlo1: associated
[Wed Jun 28 11:58:29 2023] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 9 dBm as advertised by 3c:41:0e:5d:46:ed
[Thu Jun 29 00:11:01 2023] wlo1: disassociated from 3c:41:0e:5d:46:ed (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
[Thu Jun 29 00:11:02 2023] wlo1: authenticate with 3c:41:0e:5d:60:ed
[Thu Jun 29 00:11:02 2023] wlo1: send auth to 3c:41:0e:5d:60:ed (try 1/3)
[Thu Jun 29 00:11:02 2023] wlo1: authenticated
[Thu Jun 29 00:11:02 2023] wlo1: associate with 3c:41:0e:5d:60:ed (try 1/3)
[Thu Jun 29 00:11:02 2023] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 3c:41:0e:5d:60:ed (capab=0x1111 status=0 aid=4)
[Thu Jun 29 00:11:02 2023] wlo1: associated
[Thu Jun 29 00:11:02 2023] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 9 dBm as advertised by 3c:41:0e:5d:60:ed
[Thu Jun 29 00:15:06 2023] wlo1: deauthenticated from 3c:41:0e:5d:60:ed (Reason: 8=DISASSOC_STA_HAS_LEFT)
[Thu Jun 29 00:15:06 2023] wlo1: authenticate with 3c:41:0e:5d:46:ed
[Thu Jun 29 00:15:06 2023] wlo1: send auth to 3c:41:0e:5d:46:ed (try 1/3)
[Thu Jun 29 00:15:06 2023] wlo1: authenticated
[Thu Jun 29 00:15:06 2023] wlo1: associate with 3c:41:0e:5d:46:ed (try 1/3)
[Thu Jun 29 00:15:06 2023] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 3c:41:0e:5d:46:ed (capab=0x1111 status=0 aid=1)
[Thu Jun 29 00:15:06 2023] wlo1: associated
[Thu Jun 29 00:15:06 2023] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 9 dBm as advertised by 3c:41:0e:5d:46:ed
```

And here is the last 10 minutes of skype-related messages (there is much more)

```
[Thu Jun 29 09:33:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688023980.941:54223): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:33:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688023980.941:54224): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/eno2/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:33:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688023980.941:54225): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/net/wlo1/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:38:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688024280.936:54226): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:38:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688024280.936:54227): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/eno2/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:38:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688024280.936:54228): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/net/wlo1/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:43:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688024580.934:54229): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:43:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688024580.934:54230): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/eno2/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:43:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688024580.934:54231): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/net/wlo1/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:48:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688024880.937:54232): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:48:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688024880.937:54233): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/eno2/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:48:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688024880.937:54234): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/net/wlo1/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:53:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688025180.935:54235): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:53:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688025180.939:54236): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/eno2/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:53:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688025180.939:54237): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/net/wlo1/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:58:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688025480.933:54238): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/lo/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:58:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688025480.933:54239): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/eno2/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Thu Jun 29 09:58:06 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1688025480.933:54240): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/net/wlo1/speed" pid=3651 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. What's  your MTU? `ip link` will tell you. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.

Comment: @waltinator I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: There's nothing indicating any problems in that output; it's perfectly normal. I would look in `dmesg` for any interesing wifi related messages when the performance drops. You should probably also `lshw -C network` and `iwconfig` to show us what networking hardware you have and what mode it operates in.

Comment: Thanks @vidarlo. I have updated the question, and I think there might be something interesting in the dmesg -- could skype be at fault?

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, it's that your network drops the connection often and requires your computer to reauthenticate. This can be a sign of noise or poor connectivity. It's not skype related.

Comment: @vidarlo The wifi symbol appears strong (whatever that means). Could this affect ubuntu machines more than windows? My office colleague does not seem to be affected on his windows laptop.